# Upload to Google Drive using API C# from web user

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, google-drive-api, google-api-dotnet-client

Ultimately I'm trying to upload a document from the user's file system via MVC .NET web site to Google Drive, which utilizes a service account.

I'm not sure if I'm implementing the appropriate design to accomplish the upload but I am getting hung up on the path of the file to be uploaded.

## Web

```
@Html.TextBox("file", "file", new { type = "file", id = "fileUpload" })
```

## Controller

```
public ActionResult GoogleDriveList(GoogleDrivePageVM vm, HttpPostedFileBase file)

File _file = new File();

var _uploadFile = System.IO.Path.GetFileName(file.FileName);
byte[] byteArray = System.IO.File.ReadAllBytes(_uploadFile);
```

Error occurs on the ReadAllBytes statement.  It could not find file 'C:\Program Files (x86)\IIS Express\Map of Universe.txt'.  The file name is correct but the path is not.

```
byte[] byteArray = System.IO.File.ReadAllBytes(_uploadFile);  
System.IO.MemoryStream stream = new System.IO.MemoryStream(byteArray);
```

... Google Drive file stuff goes here

Then upload the file from the stream.

```
FilesResource.InsertMediaUpload request = _service.Files.Insert(body, stream, body.MimeType);
request.Upload();
```

So, am I going down the right path using the HTML file helper?  And if so, what's the trick to get the path to work correctly?  Also, I want to be able to support file sizes up to 500 MB (if that makes a difference).

Comment: How is the file for the string being parsed? If the file is entered into the textbox, may need to verify that string is formatted correctly so the ReadAllBytes works correctly.

Comment: The user picks a file from what looks like the windows file explorer dialog.  There isn't an option to type in a file name.  The filename shows "Map of Universe.txt", which is the file I selected but the ReadAllBytes statement is including a bogus path.

Comment: Please note that the model-view-controller tag is for questions about the pattern. There is a specific tag for the ASP.NET-MVC implementation.

Answer (score 0):

If your getting the filename from a user selected windows file explorer dialog, then you shouldn't be using the below as will just strip out the filename without the path into your upload file variable and I am assuming that bogus path is where your're running the code from, so ReadAllBytes is trying to read from that path with the filename

var _uploadFile = System.IO.Path.GetFileName(file.FileName)

just change so it has that full path and filename you need to use in ReadAllBytes

var _uploadFile = file.FileName

Comment: Still getting file not found and looking for it with a bogus path.